# Error while configuring jmagick on macOS

Tags: macos, jmagick

I am trying to configure jmagick for image comparison. On running the below command:

```
./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-6/ --with-magick-inc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/ --with-magick-inc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-6/include/ImageMagick-7 --with-magick-lib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-6/lib/
```

I am getting the below error:

```
checking for MagickCore-config... /usr/local/bin/MagickCore-config
checking magick/api.h usability... no
checking magick/api.h presence... no
checking for magick/api.h... no
configure: error: 'Unable to find ImageMagick header files'
```

Comment: Try seeing if you have that file `find /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick -name api.h`

Comment: Try listing all the files in the ImageMagick package you installed and searching there `brew ls --verbose imagemagick | grep "api.h"`

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help. With the commands I am not getting results. I just googled it and find out that api.h was removed from latest imagemagick. I have 7.0.8-6 imagemagick version. If possible can you please help configuring it.

Comment: I don't know much about the Java port. I'll **guess** it doesn't support ImageMagick version 7. So I would try removing v7 Imagemagick `brew rm --force imagemagick` and then reinstalling v6 with `brew install imagemagick@6`